# Populate dropdown based on another dropdown selection using Spring MVC

Tags: spring, drop-down-menu, html-select

I filled a dropdown list with data from a database table and I have a second one which I want to display information based on the data displayed in the first dropdown. Is there any way I could do this in SPRING? Or could you tell me any other good way to do this?

These are the dropdown-lists:

```
<select name="Oras" class="drop-down">
  <option th:each="oras : ${orase}"
          th:text="${oras}"
          th:value="${oras}"></option>
</select>
<select name="Baza sportiva" class="drop-down" path="">
  <option th:each="bazaSportiva : ${bazeSportive}" th:text="${bazaSportiva.nume}"
                    th:value="${bazaSportiva}">
</option>
</select>
```

I created a controller which decides what data should be displayed in the first dropdown(from the database):

@RequestMapping(value="")
public String afisareOrase(Model model){

```
ArrayList<BazaSportiva> bazeSportive = (ArrayList<BazaSportiva>) bazaSportivaDao.findAll();
ArrayList<String> orase = new ArrayList<String>();
for(BazaSportiva bazaSportiva : bazeSportive){
    String oras = bazaSportiva.getOras();
    if(!orase.contains(oras)){
        orase.add(oras);
    }
}
model.addAttribute("orase", (Iterable) orase);
return "platforma/services";
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a javascript/jquery code in order to send an AJAX request upon the selection of any option within the first drop-down in order to fetch the second set of your data from database.

then after the AJAX response with its data went back to your AJAX function, use another javascript/jquery function to access to the second select tag (using id/class) and fill it up with the acquired data!

Refer to this youtube video tutorial for understand the concept behind this and implement it in your own code -> [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UliJeDbc4cw)